# Undefined reference for unoptimised constexpr used as default parameter

Tags: c++, linker, c++14, constexpr, undefined-reference

I do not understand why the below code compiles with GCC optimised, but fails to link with "undefined reference to `base::A_VAL'" when unoptimised. Am I doing something dodgy? Is this something that's a compiler bug (never is)? This is with g++ 5.4.0 on Ubuntu.

base.h:

```
class base {
public:
    static constexpr unsigned int A_VAL{0x69U};
};
```

derived.h:

```
#include "base.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class derived : public base
{
public:
    int some_func(void) {
        cout << "Some func" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

concrete.h:

```
#include "derived.h"

#include <utility>

class concrete : public derived
{
public:
    concrete(int a, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> data = {A_VAL, A_VAL}) {
        some_func();
        std::cout << "First: " << data.first << " Second: " << data.second << endl;
    }
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "concrete.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    concrete c{1};

    c.some_func();
}
```

> g++ -O2 -std=c++14 -o test test.cpp

Fine.

> g++ -O0 -std=c++14 -o test test.cpp

```
/tmp/ccm9NjMC.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `base::A_VAL'
test.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `base::A_VAL'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When optimizing GCC is probably able to determine (after inlining an constant folding) that the body of `concrete`'s constructor can be replaced pretty much by

```
some_func();
std::cout << "First: " << A_VAL << " Second: " << A_VAL << endl;
```

[Since `operator<<` for the standard stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) class takes integers by value, and `A_VAL` is a constant expression, the call above doesn't require there to be any storage for `A_VAL`. Its value is just plugged in. As such, GCC doesn't need there to be an out of class definition for `A_VAL`, as is normally required for static class members.

When not optimizing, GCC quite likely initializes the pair object. [`std::pair`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) takes objects by reference, and a reference requires an object to bind to. So the the definition of `A_VAL` becomes required and so the linker complains.

You need to define the object somewhere (pre C++17)

```
// At namespace scope
constexpr unsigned base::A_VAL;
```

Or switch to compiling as C++17. Then `A_VAL` (like all `constexpr` static members data) will be implicitly an inline variable, and the compiler will resolve its definition by itself.

Comment: OK. I think I get you (this is obviously test code, as opposed to my real code). How do I fix this!?

Comment: @Joe - Just added it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how`constexpr` affecting this, but you just declared static class variable, but not defined it. I.e. usually you need to have `constexpr unsigned int base::A_VAL{0x69U};` somewhere in .cpp file.